# Parsing doubles separated by minus/hyphen

Tags: c++, c++17

Am trying to parse hyphen separated string that contains double type values but facing problem in some specific cases.

Program snippet :-

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

std::pair<double,double> parsedouble(std::string currentValue)
{
        const size_t rangePos = currentValue.find('-', 1);
        double first,second;
        std::stringstream(currentValue.substr(0, rangePos)) >> first;
        std::stringstream(currentValue.substr(rangePos + 1)) >> second;
        std::pair<double,double> pairobj= make_pair(first, second);
        return pairobj;
}

int main()
{
    //first case
    std::string value1 = "-22-22";
    std::pair<double,double> output1 = parsedouble(value1);
    cout << output1.first << "," << output1.second << std::endl;
    
    //Second case
    std::string value2 = "2.22507e-308-1.79769e+308"; //double min and max range
    std::pair<double,double> output2 = parsedouble(value2);
    cout << output2.first << "," << output2.second << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Here first case is working fine but as second case contains exponential value so parsing is not happening correctly.

here I am looking for the solution if we can identify and parse double value?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the token that separates your two number strings, namely `'-'`, can also occur within the numbers. One approach for dealing with this is to let the parser consume one `double`, then manually advance the stream one character, then let the parser consume one more `double`.

This isn't very pretty, nor very robust against malformed input, but it does solve your problem:

```
std::pair<double,double> parsedouble2(const std::string & currentValue)
{
  double first, second;
  std::stringstream ss(currentValue);
  ss >> first;
  char separator;
  ss.read(&separator, 1);
  assert(separator == '-');
  ss >> second;
  return std::make_pair(first, second);
}
```

The `assert(seperator == '-')` line isn't really meant to provide any kind of robustness against malformed inputs. It's there to convey to you that the one character read on the line before, in order to advance the stream by one, is the token separator `'-'`.